# Make bg image full width and scroll to view rest of image

Tags: html, css

I have an image that i want to use as the background for my webpage. I need the image to be 100% width of the browser I then want it so that you can scroll to see the rest of the image.

The image that I am using higher than wider (hence the need for scrolling).

Everything I seem to use makes the image the full width but does not scroll so you cannot see the full image.

This currently makes the image the full width but it only visible when there things in the same div tag:
**CSS**

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.bg {
    background-image: url("Assets/Images/background.png");
    width: 100%;
    background-position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover ;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg">
        </div>

    </body> </html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `<img src="path"/>`  instead of background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use 2 sections: one for background and the other for content.

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;  
}
.bg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.content {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549416878-30862a3e49e7" alt="">
</div>
<section class="content">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet fatback shoulder meatloaf capicola, ground round cupim sausage. Sausage pork loin pastrami pork belly biltong, spare ribs ball tip doner leberkas pork filet mignon bacon chicken t-bone rump. Tri-tip jerky ball tip brisket alcatra jowl pork t-bone strip steak doner venison andouille drumstick. Beef ribs frankfurter ball tip chuck ham hock strip steak cow sirloin meatloaf. Capicola hamburger pork belly pancetta ham turducken pastrami, cow meatball ribeye spare ribs. Burgdoggen sausage porchetta, kielbasa ham hock pancetta strip steak sirloin meatloaf shank ribeye.

Cupim drumstick swine pork sirloin rump pig doner fatback. Sausage beef jowl pork chop landjaeger buffalo cow short loin corned beef bresaola. Sausage t-bone kielbasa turducken hamburger, jerky tri-tip brisket. Spare ribs tenderloin buffalo, biltong sausage beef ribs jowl pancetta pork chop prosciutto cupim shankle. Prosciutto drumstick kielbasa, bresaola pastrami flank pig pork loin. Prosciutto chicken sausage pig bresaola, sirloin strip steak tenderloin flank short loin boudin drumstick.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Had to add `width: 100%;` to `.bg img {}` to get it to work for my image. Thanks for you help here

Answer (score 0):

You can use an img tag :

```
<body>
    <img class="bg" src="Assets/Images/background.png" alt="background">
</body>
```

and set his position as fixed :

```
img.bg {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't allow me to scroll to view the rest of the image.